# Android video streaming with no sound

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am coding an android application, which is streaming video from rtsp soruces. For most of the rtsp URIs application works fine. But for some URIs video is played without any sound. When I check log files it says "audiohardware pcm playback is going to standby".

Second problem is video freezes after few minutes of streaming.

I think the problem is about streaming video encoding.

Thanks in advance.

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(live);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse(liveUrlString);

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(MyVideoViewPreparedListener);
videoView.setOnErrorListener(myVideoViewErrorListener);

videoView.start();
```